# Statement object has been closed in querying from Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, amazon-redshift

On attempting to execute a simple query on a table (dimensions: 1,131,714,069 rows by 22 columns), I am running into the error:

`[Amazon][JDBC](12080) Statement object has been closed.`

Research online has unfortunately not provided much insight into this error.

I will not encounter this error each time I execute a query; so far it seems that its occurrence is unpredictable. The query that most recently caused this error looked was a very simple `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE` with no subqueries and only one condition in the `WHERE` clause.

The query was busy for about 22 minutes before failing, however after waiting a few minutes, then running it again, it completed successfully in a matter of seconds. That being said, this kind of unpredictability and unreliability is exactly what I'm trying to prevent against.

If it helps, the IDE that I am using to connect to my Redshift database is [TeamSQL](https://teamsql.io/).

What could be causing this error, and what steps could I take to prevent it?

Comment: Possibly a statement or session timeout? If your initial query ran for 22 minutes, it might have been killed because it took too long (or maybe it took so long because of network connectivity issues that were only killed/closed after a long timeout).

Comment: That's entirely possible. I'm going to look at setting a shorter connection timeout, because waiting that long only for the query to fail is not ideal. In your estimation would this generally be happening on my end, or on the Redshift side? I've connected to this Redshift database from multiple wireless networks, and even through a wired connection and still get these kinds of query failure issues.

Comment: How busy were the queues on Redshift during the times this occurs? Perhaps the all the slots on queue the query is running on were occupied and a timeout occurred in your application while it waited for a slot to become free. Alternatively, are there any WLM rules in place that abort queries that run for longer than a certain amount of time?

Comment: It's very possible that the queues on Redshift were busy at the time, and that such rules exist. I'm looking into this, and will need to get in touch with the server administrator. These are great suggestions and certainly make sense, thank you. Out of curiosity do you know if the IDE might come into play on these kinds of JDBC errors, if it is more of an issue on the Redshift side, or if it could be either?

Comment: probably teamsql is losing connection. to prove. create an micro ec2 instance, use screen or tmux to ensure session is stable (does not rely on connection to your ip). use psql to run your query on redshift. then try again and again and see if it ever fails. if it always works then that proves its down to teamsql connection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have psql installed so I am giving that a try. Coming from MSSQL Server it's tough that no IDE with Redshift can come close to the reliability of SQL Server.